# Duplicate tag: [matterjs] - [matter.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request, synonym-request

**[matterjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matterjs)**

- Questions: 103
- Created: 5 years, 5 months
- Viewed: 28 times
- Editors: 2
- About:

  > Matter.js is a 2D rigid body physics engine for the web written in JavaScript.

**[matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matter.js)**

- Questions: 89
- 4 years, 8 months ago
- Viewed: 28 times
- Editors: 1
- About:

  > Matter.js is a JavaScript 2D rigid body physics engine for the web

---

Since these are clearly duplicate tags, could we burninate one, or create a synonym?

---

My suggestion is to **keep** the [matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matter.js) tag.

Other JS libraries often have a `.` in there tag;

- [three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/three.js)
- [highlight.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highlight.js) <sup>(same issue)</sup>
- [text.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/text.js)

Comment: Because I'll need a total of 5 score on the tag; *Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag*

Comment: Mods can merge (and synonymize) duplicate tags. I think it's safe to do in this case, but any preference for the main/target tag?

Comment: It seems like most of the JS libraries, ending in `.js` have the `.js` in the tag name, therefore I guess we'll need to use [tag:matter.js] as the main tag.

Comment: matterjs has been merged into and made a synonym of matter.js

Answer (score -5):

It appears that this question has been tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so I'm going to answer.

---

[matterjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matterjs) has been tagged as a synonym of [matter.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matter.js). The mods have done it already.

Comment: Did this really warrant an answer?